# Open Source Map Framework For Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, maps, openstreetmap

I've been looking around for a few hours for a cocoa framework for Open Street Map, but have had no success.  Are there any open source map frameworks for cocoa?

Comment: Apparently there aren't any, but maybe use Leaflet in WebView?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you don't point out what kind of framework (map viewing, map rendering, data processing, ...), license, ...
There seem to be at least a few Map viewing widgets in objective C which seems to be cocoa?
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks

Comment: It wanted to use it for drawing lines and other things over a map.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you’d like to embed an interactive, OpenStreetMap-based map into a native iOS or macOS application. The OpenStreetMap Wiki has a listing of map frameworks for [iOS](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS#Maps) and [macOS](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MacOS#Maps).

One option is the [Mapbox iOS SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/) or [Mapbox macOS SDK](https://mapbox.github.io/mapbox-gl-native/macos/). These SDKs work a lot like MapKit, but they’re open source. The default Mapbox Streets style, as well as the Mapbox-designed styles available through `MGLStyle`, are all based on OpenStreetMap data. The most straightforward way to draw a line atop the map is to add an `MGLPolyline` annotation to an `MGLMapView`. If you want to add a line beneath labels, as if the line is part of the map, you can create an `MGLShapeSource` containing an `MGLPolylineFeature`, then add an `MGLLineStyleLayer` based on that shape source to the map’s style.

(Full disclosure: I work for Mapbox and also contribute to OpenStreetMap in my spare time.)